# Centos 7 Oracle VM - Unable ping default gateway

Tags: centos, networking, virtualbox

Update: I have configured NAT as adapter 1 and Host Only as adapter 2. However, ping default gateway (192.168.56.1) returns "Destination Host Unreachable".

### Any advice thanks!

I am stuck for 1 week now. Couldn't find any solution. Appreciate your help.

I manually configure to static IP but encounter below errors:

Error Screen: (ping 192.168.56.1)

[image]

Default Gateway: (route -n)
[image]

ifcfg file (ifcfg-enp0s3)

[image]

ifcfg file (ifcfg-lo)
[image]

Adapter Setting: (ifconfig)
[image]

Network Setting: (less /etc/sysconfig/network)

[image]

Oracle VM Box Network Setting

[image]

[image]

Comment: In my setup, i have first interface set to NAT and second as host only. This way i have access to internet and can putty into static ip on the VMs too. Try adding it that way if you need to access Internet too

Answer (score 2):

You have a host-only adapter, which only allows communication within the subnet it is attached to.

Host only adapters don't have a gateway, so you won't be able to ping it.

If you are looking to communicate with the rest of the internet from that VM, you will need to connect an additional network adapter and choose "NAT" or "Bridged" mode.

Good luck, you're on the right track!

References:

- https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/UserManual.html#network_hostonly
- https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=56018

Comment: Great thanks! yes I am new to Linux. Still long way ahead

Comment: This is really not a Linux problem, but a VirtualBox networking problem. You would have had the same problem with a Windows vm running on a Windows hosted VirtualBox.